# How to set button style (theme) for a Gridview through an adapter

Tags: android, button

I have a Gridview which I populate with buttons using an adapter:-

```
public class GridViewButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
...
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button textBtn;
        if (convertView == null) {
            textBtn = new Button(mContext);
            textBtn.setMinHeight(150);
            textBtn.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,60);
            textBtn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textBtn.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rgrid_buttons));
        }
        else {
            textBtn = (Button) convertView;
        }

        textBtn.setText(buttonNames[position]);
        textBtn.setId(position);

        return textBtn;
    }
```

And I have defined a shape as a `drawable`.

However, I would like to use a `theme` style for the `buttons` and I cannot find out how to apply a `theme` to a `button` through the `adapter`. For example `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored`.

I tried `new Button(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.my_theme))` but it did not work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You've got the right idea with the `ContextThemeWrapper`, but the style you want applied to the `Button` will need to be set as the `android:buttonStyle` in the theme you pass there. You can't pass the style – e.g., `R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Button_Borderless_Colored`, or a sub-style of that – directly.